# Terminate a bash script when assigning a function call into a variable

Tags: bash, exit, subshell

I have the following code to demonstrate:

```
#!/bin/bash
function demo() {

   echo "This is A"
   exit 1
   echo "This is B"
}


input=$(demo)
echo "${input}"
echo "This is C"
```

You can see if I run this script it will print out the following output:

```
This is A
This is C
```

Since I have `exit 1` function, the script did not terminate and printed the last statement `This is C`

But when I call the function like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
function demo() {

   echo "This is A"
   exit 1
   echo "This is B"
}


demo
echo "${input}"
echo "This is C"
```

Then the program terminated and did not print the last statement "This is C". The output is:

```
This is A
```

Is there an explanation for this and how do I force the script to terminate when having the `exit 1` there plus assigning the function to a variable like example given. Meaning that, no other statements should be printed after `exit 1`

Comment: Btw.: I recommend not to use internal keywords for functions. See `type test`.

Comment: `$(...)` runs the command in a subshell, and `exit` just exits from the subshell, not the original script.

Comment: What's the point of assigning to a variable if you're exiting the script? How can you use the variable?

Comment: @Barmar In large application, This script needs to exit if the function produced an error with return code 1. So, it shouldn't run other statement and terminate itself when it has error. Example calling API in demo(), something was wrong, so it's useless to assign wrong data to variable. Terminating the script and telling user what is wrong.

Comment: @Barmar thanks for your explanation about subshell exit. Now I understand why it won't exit. But if there is a way to overcome this, I appreciate your help. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check the exit status when assigning the variable, and exit the main script if it failed.

```
input=$(demo) || exit 1
```

Comment: Note that if you are using `local` keyword in a function, you need to define the variable and set its value on separate lines, e.g. `local input; input=$(demo) || exit 1`